# PHP $_POST limit

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

I send a `JSON array` from jscript to PHP via `jQuery $.post()`. It is a table of numbers of 3-4 digits and its size is 174 x 15 (rows x cols). When checking the XHR Post. I can see all values like

```
pdata[0][]  dates
pdata[0][]  Fund B1
pdata[0][]  Fund B2
pdata[0][]  Fund B3
pdata[0][]  Fund B4
pdata[0][]  Fund B5
pdata[0][]  Fund B6
pdata[0][]  Fund B7
pdata[0][]  Fund B8
pdata[0][]  Fund B9
pdata[0][]  Fund B10
pdata[0][]  Fund B11
pdata[0][]  Fund b12
pdata[0][]  Fund B13
pdata[100][]    4/30/2005
pdata[100][]    -3.16%
pdata[100][]    -3.54%
pdata[100][]    -0.52%
```

Note that the 1st index is sorted alphabetically, not numerically. Then I process that array in PHP as

```
$pdata  = $_POST['pdata']; 
print_r($pdata);
```

The problem is that about half of data is missing and `$pdata` has only about 72 elements (arrays) instead of 174. I was thinking that it is related to the PHP `post_max_size` and increased it to `30Mb`, but it didn't help.

What else could truncate an array?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. Increasing max_input_vars to 15000 fixed the problem. Is it a good idea to pass thousands of vars via POST? Would it be better to pass a huge JSON string and decode in PHP on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`max_input_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) is the directive you're looking for.

By default it's 1000, which matches to your observations ("about 72 elements" => something like `71x14 + 6`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to fix it I added this line to my htaccess file.

**php_value max_input_vars 15000**

You can change the 15000 value to whatever is suitable for your need.

Answer (score 0):

increase

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 2048
suhosin.request.max_vars = 2048
```

on php.ini and restart server

also you can add this to your .htaccess file(  no need to restart server in this condition )
but for that you have to 
check is

```
suhosin.perdir = "p"
```

is set on php.ini

you can check php.ini config default variables using

```
 phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you increase the values for following in `php.ini`

```
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

You can set the value which is suitable to your needs.

**Note:** Server Restart is necessary after changing the settings in `php.ini`.